# What is the best way to handle this type of inclusive logic in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logic

Is there a better way of handling this in Ruby, while continuing to use the symbols?

```
pos = :pos1 # can be :pos2, :pos3, etc.

if pos == :pos1 || pos == :pos2 || pos == :pos3
  puts 'a'
end

if pos == :pos1 || pos == :pos2
  puts 'b'
end

if pos == :pos1
  puts 'c'
end
```

The obvious way would be swapping out the symbols for number constants, but that's not an option.

```
pos = 3

if pos >= 1
  puts 'a'
end

if pos >= 2
  puts 'b'
end

if pos >= 3
  puts 'c'
end
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I just figured out that Ruby orders symbols in alpha/num order. This works perfectly.

```
pos = :pos2 # can be :pos2, :pos3, etc.

if pos >= :pos1
  puts 'a'
end

if pos >= :pos2
  puts 'b'
end

if pos >= :pos3
  puts 'c'
end
```

Comment: your second code seems to suggest that treating pos as number would simplify your code (not only the shown, but in other places), is that the case?

Comment: Just clarifying - if `pos` is `:pos1`, then a, b and c (and new lines) gets printed out?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way......

I would make use of the `include?` method from array:

```
puts 'a' if [:pos1, :pos2, :pos3].include? pos
puts 'b' if [:pos1, :pos2].include? pos
puts 'c' if [:pos1].include? pos
```

Comment: I would simply use `if pos == :pos1` in the last line

Comment: Hmm.. This makes sense, like checking if in a set.  It does have the overhead of those array lookups though.

Comment: I don't concern the overhead if the array contains only a few number of symbols and until you find the the code ran really slow.

Comment: I'd go with `[:pos1].include? pos` for consistency and clarity, there is a semantic difference between a scalar and an array (or set) that just happens to have only one element. The performance hit of calling `include?` on a one element array is going to be vanishingly small. If this was C then bumming cycles to avoid a function call would be idiomatic but there's little point to that in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `case` statement

```
pos = :pos1 # can be :pos2, :pos3, etc.

case pos
   when :pos1 then %w[a b c]
   when :pos2 then %w[a b]
   when :pos3 then %w[a]
end.each {|x| puts x }
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve it.  You are having to duplicate the same code within the then...  Assume that you want the same code to run.  If pos1 then do XXX but, if pos1 or pos2 then do XXX and YYYY

Comment: There has to be some repetition. None of the answers are really DRY. I just reversed the axis of the repetition here because it seemed more concise and readable for this instance. Another set of inputs and outputs may call for a different structuring.

Comment: What sort of solution you'd use depends on what the `puts 'a'` and such are in real life. DRY is a usually a good idea but treating it as immutable dogma is silly.

Comment: @mu, there you go. I edited the answer to make it a bit less immutable. Feel free to replace the arrays and the final function with whatever's actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to get your output. Which one you
want depends on your specific objections to your `if` statements.
I've added a bunch of extra formatting to make the output easier
to read.

If you don't like the logical ORs and how they separate the results
from the output, you can use a lookup table:

```
puts "Lookup table 1:"
lookup_table1 = {
    :pos1 => %w{a b c},
    :pos2 => %w{a b  },
    :pos3 => %w{a    },
}
[:pos1, :pos2, :pos3].each { |which|
    puts "\t#{which}"
    lookup_table1[which].each { |x| puts "\t\t#{x}" }
}
```

Or, if you want all the "work" in the lookup table:

```
puts "Lookup table 2:"
lookup_table2 = {
    :pos1 => lambda do %w{a b c}.each { |x| puts "\t\t#{x}" } end,
    :pos2 => lambda do %w{a b  }.each { |x| puts "\t\t#{x}" } end,
    :pos3 => lambda do %w{a    }.each { |x| puts "\t\t#{x}" } end,
}
[:pos1, :pos2, :pos3].each { |which|
    puts "\t#{which}"
    lookup_table2[which].call
}
```

If your problem is that symbols aren't ordinals, then you can
ordinalize them by converting them to strings:

```
puts "Ordinals by .to_s and <="
[:pos1, :pos2, :pos3].each { |which|
    puts "\t#{which}"
    if which.to_s <= :pos3.to_s
        puts "\t\ta"
    end
    if which.to_s <= :pos2.to_s
        puts "\t\tb"
    end
    if which.to_s <= :pos1.to_s
        puts "\t\tc"
    end
}
```

Or you could monkey patch a comparison operator into the Symbol
class (not recommended):

```
puts "Ordinals by Symbol#<="
class Symbol
    def <= (x)
        self.to_s <= x.to_s
    end
end
[:pos1, :pos2, :pos3].each { |which|
    puts "\t#{which}"
    if which <= :pos3
        puts "\t\ta"
    end
    if which <= :pos2
        puts "\t\tb"
    end
    if which <= :pos1
        puts "\t\tc"
    end
}
```

Or you could use a lookup table to supply your ordinal values:

```
puts "Ordinals through a lookup table:"
ordinal = {
    :pos1 => 1,
    :pos2 => 2,
    :pos3 => 3,
}
[:pos1, :pos2, :pos3].each { |which|
    puts "\t#{which}"
    if ordinal[which] <= 3
        puts "\t\ta"
    end
    if ordinal[which] <= 2
        puts "\t\tb"
    end
    if ordinal[which] <= 1
        puts "\t\tc"
    end
}
```

Those are the obvious ones off the top of my head. It is hard to say what would be best without more specifics on what your problem with your `if` approach is; your second example indicates that what you really want is a way to make symbols into ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

More generically, you can use this:

```
pos = :pos3
arr = [:pos1,:pos2,:pos3]
curr = 'a'

idx = arr.length
while idx > 0
  puts curr if arr.last(idx).include? pos
  curr = curr.next
  idx -= 1
end
```

Or this, for your specific example:

```
puts 'a'
puts 'b' if pos != :pos3
puts 'c' if pos == :pos1
```